# Make user defined language in Notepad++ work regardless of theme

Tags: less, notepad++, user-defined

I have imported a Less style that a developer had recommended on [this website](http://lesscss.org), but there is a slight problem - it is made for specific themes only.

Without editing any XML files, is there any way to get this language file working regardless of theming? Like the built-in languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language file working *regardless* of the theme – as far as I know the answer is no. [Also check here.](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/69e98f06)

If you do not want to edit XML files, you can still change colors by selecting `Define your language...` item in menu `Language` and change the colors of syntax categories using color pickers.

Adding your language into list of built-in languages is not easily possible unless you wish to play with N++ sources. You are supposed to use user-defined languages for standard tasks. However you can:

- disable all unnecessarly languages in `Language menu` section in `Preferences` window and uncheck the `Make language menu compact` so you will get flat list of languages in menu.
- access your language menu item faster by pressing <kbd>Alt+L</kbd>, then 2×<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>